# Preload linked php page before viewing in browser?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, preload

So I have a php helpdesk script and I was wondering if it was possible to preload any page the user wants to view before the browser switches to it?

Like if the user is one page1.php and clicks on a link that leads to page2.php; is it possible to have a loading gif or something pop up; the next page is loaded and then the browser instantly changes the view from that of page1.php to page2.php.
In short, visually eliminating the page loading process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: heres a good example you can do with jQuery http://runnable.com/UfN8nZpQJxBgAAPq/how-to-create-page-preloader-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Do users ever go to Page 2 without going to page one? One possible solution would be to load both when the user browses to the page, hide page 2, and then when the user 'navigates' hide the first page and show the second page. They'd both be loaded, so you'd not need any spinner.

The HTML:

```
<div id="page1">
  This is page one.

  <div onclick="showNextPage()">Go to page two</span>
</div>

<div id="page2">
  Page two.
</div>
```

The JS:

```
function showNextPage()
{
  $("#page1").hide();
  $("#page2").show();
};
```

The CSS

```
#page2 {
  display:none
}
```

Is that helpful? Probably need to know more about your implementation to make a better suggestion :).

Comment: It's a dynamic script. A user can go to several pages from page1 so it's not feasible to preload all pages. The next page could also be dependent on input on page1.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure it's possible just using PHP; this is a great use case for using AJAX to pull new data from the server without a page refresh. I like using backbone as a javascript framework; seems like some people have used it with PHP: http://foysalmamun.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/practice-backbone-js-with-php-example-1/